# Using JQuery eq to set value of appended inputs

Tags: jquery

I have a form where users can append additional text inputs.  These text inputs are `dna_segment_start[]` and `dna_segment_end[]`.

Once a value has been entered in the first input for `dna_segment_end[]`, I want to set that value to the next `dna_segment_start[]` input and so on (dna_segment_end => next dna_segment_start).

I've looked at using [.eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) but not sure how to handle this say in:

```
$('[name=dna_segment_end]').keyup(function(){


});
```

In the form, the first fields appear thus:

```
  <tr id="first_segment">
    <td align="left"><div class="required"><input name="dna_segment_name[]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" /></div></td>
    <td align="left"><div class="required"><input name="dna_segment_start[]" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" /></div></td>
    <td align="left"><div class="required"><input name="dna_segment_end[]" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" /></div></td>
    <td align="left"><div class="required"><input class="picker" name="dna_segment_colour[]" type="text" size="5" /></div></td>
    </tr>
```

Then there is the ability to append additional rows:

```
$('#add_dna_segment').click(function(){
$("#first_segment").after("<tr><td><div class='required'><input name='dna_segment_name[]' type='text' size='15' maxlength='30' /></div></td><td><div class='required'><input name='dna_segment_start[]' type='text' size='6' maxlength='6' /></div></td><td><div class='required'><input name='dna_segment_end[]' type='text' size='6' maxlength='6' /></div></td><td><input class='picker' name='dna_segment_colour[]' type='text' size='5' /></td></tr>");
```

Basically I just want start input val on the next row to equal the end input value on the previous row.

**EDITED**

I'm currently now using

```
$("input[name*='dna_segment_end']").keyup(function(){
$('input[name*=dna_segment_start]:last-child').val($(this).val());
});
```

This adds the value of `dna_segment_end` to all inputs with the name `dna_segment_start`, but it needs to be just the next input with that name.  I think [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) maybe the key here and incrementing the index of the eq key... something like this I guess (but this only works on the first iteration of `dna_segment_start`

```
$("input[name*='dna_segment_end']").keyup(function(){
    var i = 0;
$('input[name*=dna_segment_start]').eq(i + 1).val($(this).val());
});
```

You can have a play with a [test page](http://mdhs-nix-005.meddent.uwa.edu.au/bioinformatics/admin/test.php)

Comment: Its difficult to understand your question, can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: Added some markup to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$('input[name=dna_segment_end]:last-child').val()` to capture the value of the last input.. and then use it

```
$('#add_dna_segment').click(function(){
    $("#first_segment").after("<input type='text' value='" + $('input[name=dna_segment_end]:last-child').val() + "'"); // use your html here..this is just an example on how to set the value...
});
```

Comment: Problem with specifying the value in append is that the value is necessarily entered.  Also the value being appended is always the first value entered.  I've edited my OP...

Comment: did you mean you want to append the new input to the #first_segment?
You might be interested in http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Have a look at this test page http://mdhs-nix-005.meddent.uwa.edu.au/bioinformatics/admin/test.php

Comment: Add some dna segments and enter a value in the first end input.  That value goes into the next start input.  I want to do the same for whatever new segments are added...

Answer (score 0):

if you only want that when you type in one input the second get the same value then here you go:

```
<input id="input">
<input id="output">


var input = $("#input");
input.keyup(function(){
    $("#output").val(input.val());
});
```

Otherwise explain a little further ;)

Comment: Notice these inputs are using array names only and the user can add as many fields as they want..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/EUV5J/

HTML

```
<input name="dna_segment_start[]" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="dna_start" />
<input name="dna_segment_end[]" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="dna_end" />
```

jQuery

```
$("#dna_end").keyup(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $("#dna_start").val(v);
});


$("#dna_start").keyup(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $("#dna_end").val(v);
});
```

Comment: No, it needs to be more dynamic (no ids and and an unknown number of inputs)